# How to Supress implicit return from a closure with Void return type in Swift

Tags: swift, return, closures, implicit, completion-block

lets consider we have a closure like: (used as completionHandler)

```
func doSomething (completionHandler : (done : Bool)->Void )->Void {
      ...
     completionHandler(true)
}
```

now if we want to do something like that :

```
doSomething({ (done : Bool)-> Void
  var data : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
  data.setValue("data1", forKey: "data1")   // 1
  data.setValue("data2", forKey: "data2")   // 2
  data.setValue("data3", forKey: "data3")   // 3
})
```

it returns on line // 1 and ignores the remaining lines because the returning type of `setValue` of `NSDictionary` is `Void`. My Question is, is there a way to suppress this behaviour?

Comment: currently I am relying on this :    
var ret_consume = data.setValue("data1", forKey: "data1")

Comment: Try to put these 4 lines in parenthesis { }.

Comment: @Amit89 this gives compile time error .... Expression is Ambiguous without  any context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your example with your code (with minor tweaks) and didn't have the problem you described. I used a swift dictionary instead though, since I have no knowledge about Obj-C.

```
func doSomething(completionHandler: Bool -> Void) {
    completionHandler(true)
}

doSomething() { finished in
    var data = [String: String]()
    data.updateValue("data1", forKey: "data1")  // 1
    data.updateValue("data2", forKey: "data2")  // 2
    data.updateValue("data3", forKey: "data3")  // 3

    for (key, value) in data {
        println("Key: \(key) & Value: \(value)")
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Key: data2 & Value: data2
Key: data1 & Value: data1  // Not sure why data1 is second here
Key: data3 & Value: data3
```

I doubt using `NSDictionary` could be the cause of it, maybe something else is causing it to return?

Comment: You are missing the whole point here. You are doing assignment. Try creating a function which returns Void and then replace that assignments of step 1,2,3 via function like doAssign(data, key, value) and then see what happens.......

Comment: Well, I basically just used your code. Not sure what's the difference. I'll look into it more in a moment.

Comment: The first data appears second because a dicctionary cannot be ordered.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. In my example, I recreated your function `doSomething(_:)` returning `Void` with a function as a parameter which also returns `Void`. Then I called `doSomething(_:)` with a function, setting up a dictionary and returns `Void`. Exactly like your code except I used a swift dictionary. Please explain in your question what exactly you want, because if the code you've provided isn't what you want, then we can't do much for you. @Kutyel: I know it's not ordered but why does it always show as second?

Comment: I was using NSDictionary but NSMutableDictionary was supposed to be used  here..... my mistake ..... Thanks guys for giving time and helping ....

Answer (score 0):

You're having this problem because you are creating an `NSDictionary`, which is not mutable. You'll need to use an `NSMutableDictionary` to do this.

My code:

```
import Foundation

func doSomething (completionHandler: (done: Bool) -> Void ) -> Void {
    completionHandler(done: true)
}

doSomething({ (done: Bool) -> Void in
    var data: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    data.setValue("data1", forKey: "data1")   // 1
    data.setValue("data2", forKey: "data2")   // 2
    data.setValue("data3", forKey: "data3")   // 3

    for (key, value) in data {
        println("Key: \(key) & Value: \(value)")
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me, it was my Dumb mistake ...... but I am confused why it was not giving run time error...

Comment: @MAbdulSami This is the answer to your problem, but you should definitely check what prevents you from using Swift types. It's much better integrated in Swift itself, by supporting subscript etc.

Comment: I was just a little afraid of using them, but now I am afraid of using NS objects instead :D